# Extract content of the nth line into a character vector

Tags: r

I have a large text file that I read into R using `readLines`. I then identified certain line numbers (using the return value of `grep`).  Now I would like to get the contents of those lines into a character vector. I am not sure what function to use to extract the contents.

```
textFile = "textfile.txt"
contents = readLines(textFile, n=-1) 
reg = "\\*{3}"
LineNumbers = grep(reg, contents)
print(LineNumbers)
# 234, 495, 589
```

How do I get the contents of the 234th, 495th, and 589th lines into a character vector?

Comment: `grep(reg, contents, value=TRUE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`contents` is an array. You can just use the line numbers as an index:

```
contents[LineNumbers]
```

Or you can directly use `grep` to get the actual values, no need to retrieve the line numbers first:

```
grep(reg, contents, value = TRUE)
```

Comment: That was simple and I just didn't realize that contents was an array. Thank you so much!